# PrototypeJS not removing select element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Given the following HTML, I'm trying to remove all form elements. The problem I'm encountering is that the `select` element is not being removed, but rather the first `option` in it is being removed each time the *remove* code is called. 
See http://jsfiddle.net/b8FfT/

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
  <div id="order_history_block">
    <div id="history_form" class="order-history-form">
      <div>Add Order Comments</div>
      <span class="field-row">
        <label class="normal" for="history_status">Status</label><br>
        <select name="history[status]" class="select" id="history_status">
          <option value="processing">Ok to Ship</option>
          <option value="pending" selected="selected">Pending</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span class="field-row">
          <label class="normal" for="history_comment">Comment</label>
          <textarea name="history[comment]" rows="3" cols="5" style="height:6em; width:99%;" id="history_comment"></textarea>
      </span>
      <div class="f-left">
        <input name="history[is_visible_on_front]" type="checkbox" id="history_visible" value="1"><label class="normal" for="history_visible"> Visible on Frontend</label>
      </div>
      <div class="f-right">
        <button id="id_79ae3bd75916862b0245fbcb3343d24e" title="Submit Comment" type="button" class="scalable save" onclick="doStuff()" style=""><span><span><span>Submit Comment</span></span></span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**JS**

```
var a = $('order_history_block').parentNode;
$(a).select('input', 'select', 'textarea').invoke('remove');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the HTMLSelectElement prototype (not the framework) has its own `remove()` method and when you call `remove()` on `<select>`s it does not traverse up the prototype chain to the `remove()` method of HTMLElement added by PrototypeJS.

2 options for you

```
$('history_status').parentNode.removeChild($('history_status'));
```

or

```
Element.remove($('history_status'));
```

I've filed a bug report for this as well

https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/issues/122

**EDIT**

Use a CSS selector and the `select()` method like this

```
$('order_history_block').up().select('select').each(function(item){
    Element.remove(item);
});
```

Comment: Looks like that'll work. How would I do it using the output of `select()`? I would like to avoid having to hardcode the `select`'s ID in there.

Comment: I added the answer above